# Set response encoding in embedded tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, catalina

Is there a way to set response encoding in embedded tomcat? By far I could only find setting URI encoding. But I need to set the response encoding.

The surprise is, standalone tomcat is by default sending data in UTF-8.

Comment: just use setCharacterEncoding method of ServletResponse class avaliable in HttpServletResponse to set response encoding if you dont want to use filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter to set your response encoding

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  

import javax.servlet.*;  

public class MyFilter implements Filter{  

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}  

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,  
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {  

    resp.setCharacterEncoding("text/plain; charset=UTF-8"); 

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);//sends request to next resource  


    }  
public void destroy() {}  
}
```

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat. I tried setting setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"). Though the HTTP response header sends the encoding, the browser is not properly showing the characters.

Comment: use setCharacterEncoding("text/html; charset=UTF-8"); see [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String))

Comment: But, the problem is it works fine on jetty and standalone tomcat. Embedded tomcat version is 8.0.12, is this a cause?

Comment: Servlet Specification is same for all containers. issue is something else. Please try to add this in web.xml <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

Comment: I am not using JSPs. It serves html directly.

Comment: add following in html page : <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

Answer (score 0):

1. Create filter:

   `package charsetFilter.classes;

   ```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

   public class CharsetFilter implements Filter{
       private String encoding;

       public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
               encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
               if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
       }

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain       next)
       throws IOException, ServletException{
           // Respect the client-specified character encoding
           // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
               if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
               request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
               /**
           * Set the default response content type and encoding
           */
           response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
               next.doFilter(request, response);
       }

           public void destroy(){}
   }`
   ```
2. Add this filter in web.xml as:

   ```
   `<filter>
           <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
           <filter-class>charsetFilter.classes.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
               <init-param>
                   <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
                   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
               </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
           <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
           <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>`
   ```
3. HTML-meta tags should be written in all HTML files:
       `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fi">
          <head>
              <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />`
4. Set your servlet as:
   `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
5. Deal with servlet requests as:
   `String input = new String(request.getParameter("foo").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "utf-8");
   String input = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("keyWord"), "UTF-8");`

Let me know if you still have problems